After Pressing"I" to add keyframe. Some options are supposed to be popped up like available,posistion, and rotation. but in my case none of them popup
After pressing I to add keyframe, some options are supposed to be popped up like Available, Posistion, and Rotation. but in my case none of them pop up.


This behavior has changed with Blender 4.2.

As Lutzi said, the key-frame inserts in Blender 4.2 are now always "LocRotScale" when pressing I.
You can get the old behavior by pressing K to select one of the other options.
You can read more about it here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/editing.html#insert-keyframe
